# Can't focus input after scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In mobile browser, when focus input text, I want this input scroll to top

```
$(this.$el).find('input, textarea').on('focus', function(e) {
  setTimeout((function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    if (pos.top > window.innerHeight) {
      var scrollTopOffset = pos.top - window.innerHeight + this.offsetHeight + 10
      $scroller.scrollTop($scroller.scrollTop() + scrollTopOffset)
    }
  }).bind(this), 500); // After the keyboard up
  $(this).focus()
})
```

after the input scroll to the correct position, can't focus the input

touch the input then focus is ok,
after that the keyboard up then the input scroll to top,
then loose the focus

How to focus the input after scroll?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Can you be a little more clear

Comment: @Deryck edited my question, dose it clear now?

Comment: Well I'm not sure why it would be unfocused after scroll but you could try putting the `$(this).focus()` **inside** the `setTimeout()` so it fires after the scroll completes

Comment: @Deryck I've tried this, still can't focus the input

Comment: Did you try on("tap") instead of on("focus") ?

Comment: @joashp any of "focus, touchend, tap"  didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this, by emulating the browser for mobile and it works.

```
$('input, textarea').on('focus', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will help you.. Thanks

```
var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
      var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
      elem.focus();
      window.scrollTo(x, y);
    }

    cursorFocus(document.getElementById('search-terms'));
```